Make pytorch __getitem__ Dataset method dependent on a parameters
I would like to work with a Pytorch custom Dataset class making the output of getitem method depending on a parameter.
class myDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, myparam, dataframe, dataframe2):
        self. myparam = myparam
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.dataframe2 = dataframe2

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        X = self.dataframe.iloc[idx].values
        y = self.dataframe2.iloc[idx].values
        
        if self.myparam == 1:
            X = ... # manipulate X in some way
        return X, y

dataset = myDataset(myparam, dataframe, dataframe2)
validation_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=val_subsampler)



The problem is that I would like to access the Dataset parameter from an instantiated data loader in such a way I can choose to manipulate or not the X data directly from the validation_loader object
There could be several workarounds to deal with this issue but I would be interested in a "good code" approach.

do you get error message? If so then show FULL error message in question (not in comments). It would be simpler if you would create minimal reproducible example

I noticed there's a space in this line after self. that shouldn't be there: self. myparam = myparam
I suspect that's what's causing your error, you should be able to do what you described without any trouble.

Might be a workaround, but technically you could already modify the Dataset param from within the data_loader object. I have a custom dataset for images, which inherits from Dataset, with one parameter being self.target_size which modifies the output size within __getitem__. Small example:
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class myDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, target_size, ...):
        self.target_size = target_size
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        X = load_image(idx)
        X = resize_image(X, self.target_size)
        return X

my_ds = myDataset(target_size=(1024, 1024), ...)
dl = DataLoader(my_ds)

batch = next(iter(dl))
print(batch.shape)  # torch.Size([1, 3, 1024, 1024])

dl.dataset.target_size = (2048, 2048)  # dl.dataset is the attribute that contains my_ds

batch = next(iter(dl))
print(batch.shape)  # torch.Size([1, 3, 2048, 2048])

It also works directly on the Dataset object:
img = my_ds.__getitem__(0)
print(img.shape)  # (3,2048,2048)

my_ds.target_size = (1024,1024)

img = my_ds.__getitem__(0)
print(img.shape)  # (3,1024,1024)

Within a training or evaluation loop you could just modify the dataset parameter I imagine. Modifying the input parameters for __getitem__ does not seem to me like the right way. I may be wrong of course.
